# ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (224, 224, 3)

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

```
import os
import cv2

path1 = os.path.abspath('/content/drive/My Drive/dogbreed/test_set/n02085620-Chihuahua')
path2 = os.path.abspath('/content/drive/My Drive/dogbreed/test_set/n02085936-Maltese_dog')
path3 = os.path.abspath('/content/drive/My Drive/dogbreed/test_set/n02088238-basset')
folder = os.path.join(path1, path2, path3)

images = []
for filename in os.listdir(folder):

  if filename.endswith(".jpg"):
    img = cv2.imread(os.path.join(folder, filename))

    if img is not None:
      images.append(img)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = np.array(images[0])
img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation = cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
plt.plot('image',img)
```

Comment: The shape of img has only one dimension (a scalar number) and so is different from the 2 dimensional array you specify by (224,224). What is images[0]? Please examine it more carefully. Resize will only resize an array of the same dimensions as the input to it.

Comment: If you are trying to enlarge a 1 pixel image, it would need to be (1,1) and not (1,). What is the structure of images[0]? Perhaps images[0] is not compatible with np.array. If images is a list of arrays, then you perhaps you can just use it directly as images[0] in resize. Or if it is a file on disk, then your need to read it using cv2.imread()

Comment: i have used images[0] from the images list where i have append the images

Comment: If the images[0] is a list of arrays, then no need to read the arrays.

Answer (score 0):

your call to

```
plt.plot('image',img)
```

is generating the error because the first and the second argument must have the same dimension.

Maybe, should you consider

```
plt.imshow(img)
```

to replace this line?